# Converting the values of the dictionary in to a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary say : `my_map_dict` which looks something like below:

```
{2: [['1', '2', '4', '4', '0', '2', '0', '0.67'], ['5', '6', '3', '8', '0', '2', '1', '0.67'], ['6', '9', '4', '9', '0', '2', '2', '0.67'], ['4', '3', '6', '9', '0', '2', '3', '1.00']], 3: [['4', '6', '6', '1', '0', '3', '0', '0.67'], ['5', '9', '4', '8', '0', '3', '1', '0.67']], 4: [['1', '9', '4', '9', '0', '4', '0', '0.67']]}
```

Where 2,3,4 are the keys of the dictionary and those lists are the values of that.

Now I want to generate a file from this say `outputfile.txt` which will take all the values of the dictionary and make that a CSV file which looks like below (desired output):

```
1,2,4,4,0,2,0,0.67
5,6,3,8,0,2,1,0.67
6,9,4,9,0,2,2,0.67
4,3,6,9,0,2,3,1.00
4,6,6,1,0,3,0,0.67
5,9,4,8,0,3,1,0.67
1,9,4,9,0,4,0,0.67
```

How can I do it?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the values of your dictionary to a single `list` of lists, and use the `csv` module to write to file:

```
import csv

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([item for sublist in d.values() for item in sublist])
```

###### output.csv

```
1,2,4,4,0,2,0,0.67
5,6,3,8,0,2,1,0.67
6,9,4,9,0,2,2,0.67
4,3,6,9,0,2,3,1.00
4,6,6,1,0,3,0,0.67
5,9,4,8,0,3,1,0.67
1,9,4,9,0,4,0,0.67
```